# How to parallelize threads in C pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading

I have N threads and they have to do job on shared data.

I am using following structure:

```
int main(){
    pthread_create(..., func, ...);
}

void *func(void *id){
    lock;
    do_job;
    unlock;
}
```

My problem is that threads seem to work sequentially. How to actually make them parallel?

Comment: Remember if you use one cpu/core then you will never get parallelized processing. It will just seem like it if you do it rigth.

Answer (score 6):

They're serialising because you're holding the lock across your entire operation.  To actually get parallelism you'd need to do something like:

```
void func(void *id) {
    lock;
    do something serialised with shared data;
    unlock;

    do something that can be parallelised safely;

    lock;
    do something else with shared data;
    unlock;
}
```

The trick (as it is in anything threaded or otherwise parallelised) is working out where you need to serialise in order to not break things.  This is **not** easy.

Comment: In your example, you're only creating 1 thread as well.  If you do create multiple threads, you'll probably want to do a pthread_join in main on the created threads. If main exits prior to the threads (which is likely) I'm pretty sure the other threads die.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of which thread is scheduled to run depend on several things:

- Thread priority
- Schedule policy
- Task attribution.

  On single CPU , unless some thread will be blocked (for example because of waiting I/O), creating several threads will not make the program running fast. Instead, it might make the program slower because of the the task switch overhead.

And also notice the difference between [concurrency and parallelism](http://blogs.oracle.com/yuanlin/entry/concurrency_vs_parallelism_concurrent_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Hold the lock for as small an operation as possible. If you don't, then the threads' order of execution degenerates into a sequential task (thread N executes and locks the resource, now thread N must finish before any other threads can resume work, thread N finished and thread N+1 executes, assumes the lock, and so forth..). Also try to interleave memory-I/O access (which I'm arbitrarily assuming is what the lock is protecting) with computation, to achieve some greater degree of parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Use [read/write locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock) if possible